# Using a type in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a large number of classes.
From this list I get a specified type

```
Type aType = Type.GetType(...);
```

Now I want to use this type in a linq statement like:

```
var aResult = from obj in scope.Extent<aType>() select obj;
```

This does not seem to be possible, as Extent does not accept Type.

Is there any way now (with .net 4.5) to call the statement?

All I want to do is to say use Type as class. Don't invoke the class, only get with linq all objects of this type from a scope.

Comment: What is `scope`? What is `Extent`?

Comment: scope is an OA Objectscope. Extent extends the scope to search for a specified object.

Comment: As in [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/using-linq-with-openaccess-orm.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an instance of `Type` as a generic type argument - not at compile time, anyway.

If you want objects of a specific type, you could do

```
var aResult = from obj in scope where obj.GetType() == aType select obj;
```

Note that this requires an *exact* type match, rather than any kind of "can be assigned to" relationship.

Also note that this will only get you a series of `object`s - again there's no compile-time way to cast things to an instance of `Type`.

Comment: "again there's no compile-time way to cast things to an instance of Type." Can you explain why?

Comment: Because, at compile time, the compiler doesn't know what's going to be in your list of types (or list of objects from which you're getting your types).

Comment: But if I have an object, I can use Convert.ChangeType(object, type). Wouldn't that be the same problem of not knowing in compile time? And why is this necessary at compile time? I wna't it at run time.

Comment: If you only want it at runtime, that's fine, and the above code will give you an `IEnumerable<object>` where you know, at runtime, that each `object` is secretly an `aType`. But at compile time you only know they are `object`s, so you can't compile any code that uses properties of `aType`. Similarly, `Convert.ChangeType(o, type)` gives you an `object` that you know at runtime is secretly a `type`.

Comment: The problem which i have with the answer, is that the scope (third party ORM - OA ) does not implement queries.

Comment: Fair enough - this isn't very relevant then.